# How can I use Linq to merge the index/value of float[] with an Dictionary<string, int_To_merge>

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, dictionary

Suppose I have a `float[]` where each position in the array has unique meaning.  Each position corresponds with an entry in the following Dictionary, where `int` refers to the array offset:

```
// The int below refers to a position within the float
Dictionary<myObjectDetail, int>
```

I'd like to join the `float[index_to_merge]` with `Dictionary<myObjectDetail,index_to_merge>` so I end up with something like

```
  Dictionary<myObjectDetail,floatvalue>
```

Can I use Linq to solve this problem, and merge these objects into a new anonymous type?

Comment: Don't u have a `Dictionary<int, myObjectDetail>` in fact?

Comment: "Can i" questions almost always end with the answer "Yes, you can." :)

Comment: @Aliostad- nope, it's the reverse where that object overrides the ToHash and Equals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using the following:

```
var newDictionary = oldDictionary.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => floats[x.Value]);
```

Here `oldDictionary` is you original `Dictionary<myObjectDetail, int>` and now your `newDictionary` is `Dictionary<myObjectDetail,floatvalue>` which is what you wanted.

Comment: Makes sense, for some reason I thought it would be much harder then that!  I was attempting a select from...

Comment: I will accept the answer in 3 minutes, or however long it takes me to buy a Subway sandwich.  Likely the latter.  Thanks Mahesh!